# How to remove multiple empty paragraph tags in woocommerce product list

Tags: html, css, wordpress, tags, woocommerce

How to remove multiple empty space `p[paragraph]` tags i have tried by using the code `p:empty{display:none}` but it didn't applied for all other `p` tags for my site.

Comment: can you share screenshot of page where multiple empty P tags execution.

Comment: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/896088/689ca936c5b1897109af84dbd7152a87 check the link and tell me the solution

Comment: Remove it from css. Only 1 is require.

Comment: yes i tried that also but its not removing this is the website link http://www.jourferieparis.com/eshop-femme/

Comment: That is &nbsp; from admin. go to that product in admin and check product content. At end of content there is `<p>&nbsp;,p>` , Remove that.

Comment: yes but whenever i will edit the product it is automatically creating that tag

Comment: then it is issue of your theme or plugin you are using for product.

Comment: i have used the the plugin disableautowp also then also its coming